# Make DynamoDB table a consumer for Kinesis Data Stream using CDK

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-cdk, amazon-kinesis

I would like to enabled enhanced fan-out on a Kinesis Data Stream and make a DynamoDB a consumer using CDK.  I found the [CfnStreamConsumer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_kinesis.CfnStreamConsumer.html) construct to register a consumer with a Kinesis data stream but I can't figure out how to connect the dynamodb table because the construct only accepts the kinesis stream arn.

I've seen posts of people using CfnStreamConsumer with [EventSourceMapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda.EventSourceMapping.html) but the target was a lambda.

Does anyone know how to make a DynamoDB table a consumer of a Kinesis Data Stream?

Code:

```
const eventStream = new kinesis.Stream(...)

new dynamoDb.Table(this, 'table', {
  tableName: `event-lease`,
  billingMode: dynamoDb.BillingMode.PROVISIONED,
  readCapacity: 10,
  writeCapacity: 10,
  partitionKey: { name: 'leaseKey', type: dynamoDb.AttributeType.STRING }
});

const streamConsumer = new kinesis.CfnStreamConsumer(this, 'stream-consumer', {
  consumerName: `event-lease`,
  streamArn: eventStream.streamArn
});

const kinesisConsumerPolicyStmt = new PolicyStatement({
  resources: [streamConsumer.attrConsumerArn],
  actions: ['kinesis:SubscribeToShard'],
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DynamoDB cannot be a consumer of a Kinesis Data Stream, it can only be a producer.

If you want your events to enter DynamoDB then you should stream to Lambda and insert the events from there.